# DIV alignment like table

Tags: css, html

I am having trouble with aligning DIV tags. I am making a very basic page with Lightbox. In the old days, I would just make a table, align every cell vertically to the bottom, and move on. But trying to use DIV tags, having some trouble. When I do the code below, its pretty jumbled. 2 shorter DIV containers may align on one "row". Can someone point to me the best way to achieve this?

HTML CODE

```
<div id='wrapper' style='width:924px;>
    <div style='float:left;width:308px;background-color:green'>
        <a href='' title='title' rel='lightbox[10]' title=''>
            <img src='' width='250px'>
        </a>
        <br/>
        TITLE
    </div>
    <div style='float:left;width:308px;background-color:green'>
        <a href='' title='title' rel='lightbox[10]' title=''>
            <img src='' width='250px'>
        </a>
        <br/>
        TITLE
    </div>
    <div style='float:left;width:308px;background-color:green'>
        <a href='' title='title' rel='lightbox[10]' title=''>
            <img src='' width='250px'>
        </a>
        <br/>
        TITLE
    </div>
    ...
</div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: can you post a fiddle please

Comment: Sorry, new here, whats a fiddle?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ - it's a place to post your code so we can actually see it and manipulate it. handy tool. here's yours - http://jsfiddle.net/64264/

Comment: after the typo fix it looks like they are side by side, what is your goal?

Comment: Ok, I updated the fiddle with a sample image to show what is going on... http://jsfiddle.net/64264/3/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/64264/5/ use a class instead of inline styles. I'm using inline-block here instead of float. the result is the divs are aligned at the bottom instead of the top. but be aware of whitespace in the code. see how I smashed your divs together.

Comment: Thanks! I plan to use classes, was just trying to figure this out using inline style out of laziness! :) That looks like what I need. So the white space and new line in between the </div> and <div> makes a difference?

Comment: yes, I posted my comment as an answer BTW :)

Comment: Thank you! So the mistakes I made (besides not using classes, 33%, ect) were white space in between the div tags, and not using inline-block?

Comment: no, you were using float, the elements align at the top when floating.Also this is why the other images stayed there. When floating all elements try to stack so to speak, as you saw. since they were short, they just kept piling up. the width just assures only 3 divs are on a line.

Comment: No problem. Have fun!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[See this fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/64264/5) use a class instead of inline styles. I'm using `inline-block` here instead of `float`. the result is the divs are aligned at the bottom instead of the top. but be aware of whitespace in the code. see how I smashed your divs together. If there is whitespace a width of 33% is too much and will knock the third div down a line.The width of `33%` is one third of the container so they each take up the same width.

Comment: with `inline-block` , you can stick any numbers of element on 1 line with `white-space:nowrap;` set on parent, reset it to normal for childs. white-space doesn't erase white-space if any in your HTML. tere's a few methods to vanish them using: font-size,letter-spacing,word-spacing, ... imho , the only solid method is to take of them from HTML code . opening/closing brackets against each other or empty space filled with an HTML comment.

Comment: That was a bit confusing, but yeah, I took the white space out between elements.

Comment: add some info to your answer, i'll erase my comment :)

Comment: Nah, leave your comment for clarification. I thought I was pretty explicit in the answer and the fiddle though. More info is never a bad thing though as the whitespace thing is very tricky.